# How do I fetch data from Mysql to ANdroid Studio

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, textview, imageview

I need help on how do i get data and display it in "textview" and "imageview" in android studio. Im making a dictionary which is controlled in the web and the users are on android phone. Please do help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Show you java code of the activity

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your ListView properly , when you are setting an adapter to it , it throws a NullPointerException because it's still Null and not yet initialized